# VBA: how to pass text in demanded format to different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have:

```
Range("A1") = 0.0576877
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.0%"

Range("A2") = "Percentage of people: " & Range("A1")
```

I want to have a following text in the cell "A2": **"Percentage of people: 5.8 %"**

But I still got: **"Percentage of people: 0.0576877"**

I still cant find the right solution. I'm new to this, of course. Any ideas?

Comment: You change the formatting of the value, not the value - it stays the same. Just try `Range("A2") = "Percentage of people: " & Format(Range("A1"), "0.0%")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
With Range("A2")
    .value = Range("A1").value
    .NumberFormat = """Percentage of people: ""0.0%"
End With
```

In this way you can use the A2 cell (percentage) value in any math operation. Practically, "Percentage of people: " is part of the format... The "A2" cell value is not a string!